# How to compare one column of 2 large csv dataset with col1+col2 as key?

Tags: multithreading, dataframe, external-sorting

I have 2 large "dataframe"-like csv datasets, each has 4 columns. column1+column2 is the key, column4 is the value I want to compare. key1 and key2 are the same, it is able to compare the val, key1 and key2 can be duplicated, key1 has around 1M unique records, key2 has 4000 unique records.

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
key1, key2, ignore, val
```

This can be very easy using dataframe, but when it comes to 100GB of each dataset, it is not able to load all then into memory, and pandas dataframe limit 48GB size of object.

I currently have a program:

```
1. iterate dataset1 and get a unique column1 set (1M records).
2. load the set into a queue and build a threadpool.
3. Each thread will get 10k records from queue and iterate 2 datasets to build 2 hashmaps, (key1+key2) as key, and column4 as val.
4. compare hashmap and output the results to a singal CSV file.
```

This will lead to 5 hours run time. 
My question is any reasonable idea to get around 30 min of run time? Redesign the program is also acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at python hdf5 , it has a lot of functionality for bigger datasets

Comment: @pyeR_biz will take a look.